# Why does my close button not work on touchscreens?

Tags: jquery, onclick, touch

I got a close button that only shows up when an image is clicked, the image will be resized and after clicking the close button it will be resized to its origin size. Works fine on PCs but not on mobile devices. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.image').click(function (event) {
       /* code for hiding some elements and enlarging the image here */
       $('#close_button2').show();
   });
   $('#close_button2').on('touchend click', function(event){
       /* code for showing some elements and display the image in the smaller size again */
       $('#close_button2').hide();
   });
   $(document).keyup(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 27) {
                /* some code for pressing escape button */
            }
   });
});
```

Instead of `$('#close_button2').on('touchend click', function(event){` I also tried:

```
$('#close_button2').click(function (event) {
$('#close_button2').on( "vclick", function( event ) { //jQuery mobile only - there were some conflicts with my code
$('#close_button2').on(isMobile ? 'touchend' : 'click', function(event) {
$(document).on('click', '#close_button2', function(event) {
```

But nothing worked. Any ideas?

Comment: `$(document).on('touchend click', '#close_button2', function(event) {` what about `touchend` in this event delegation?

Comment: and I'm guessing $('#close_button2').on('click', function() { doesn't work

Comment: Thx! But nothing worked. I don't get it :(

Comment: It looks like `on` does not accept multiple events. If you hook them up separately they work fine. Answer using alternative using `bind` instead below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on` does not appear to like multiple events (surprised me too!).

Use `bind` instead:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/TWDZY/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.image').click(function (event) {
       /* code for hiding some elements and enlarging the image here */
       $('#close_button2').show();
   });
   $('#close_button2').bind('touchend click', function(event){
       /* code for showing some elements and display the image in the smaller size again */
       $('#close_button2').hide();
   });
   $(document).keyup(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 27) {
                /* some code for pressing escape button */
            }
   });
});
```

Comment: Thx! I tried your jsfiddle on my smartphone and it worked. But it's still not working on my site. It has to be another error. I'll check that out. Thanks for your help. Now I know it has to be something else what causes the error :)

Comment: Got it! There was an unnecessary if statement if (window.innerHeight !== screen.height) {} before the close button click function. I'm soo stupid :D